# Web page larger than screen?

Tags: html, css, web

So I've just finished developing this design just for practice. And everything is just like I wanted except for the fact that SOMETHING is larger than screen size. I've inspected the page inside the browser, checked all margins and widths, but can't seem to find what's causing it.

I have a .container div that's 1280px wide with auto margins, so it'd always be centered and everything is inside it. And that container is inside the `<body>`.

Here's the link to my zipped project. It's only a few KBs. Just one page.
http://files.fm/u/aguxkzq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position style attribute of `.laptop h1` is causing the problem.

`.laptopimage` and the next `h1` need to be `position: absolute` because they need to be positioned in relation to its wrapper which is `position:relative`.

You'll need to refactor this section.

Comment: I suggest you remove all of the position:relative, and use floats. Then you could change the margins or absolute position the section element ``.green > section``.